# Unable to generate *.c.gcov file

Tags: gcc, gcov

I have the following structure:

```
Source_code/build/unix/Makefile
Source_code/code/Lib/src/lib1/a.c
```

The `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage` options are mentioned in the gcc compilation option. It successfully generates the `a.gcda` and `a.gcno` files. And when given the following option `gcov a.c`, it gives the statistics correctly for lines executed.

But it is unable to generate the `a.c.gcov` file properly, it only contains `/* EOF */`.

It throws the following messages:

```
../../code/lib/src/lib1/a.c:creating 'a.c.gcov'
../../code/lib/src/lib1/a.c:cannot open source file
```

Please let me know to generate the `a.c.gcov` file.

Comment: I have also tried using : gcov -o ../../code/lib/src/lib1/a* : from source_code/build/unix : it doesn't show the cannot open source file but the gcov file has only /* EOF */

Comment: Are you sure, that -fprofile-arcs and -ftest-coverage options are used in linking step (last step of compilation or every subproject)? What is your OS? How huge are a.*gc* files?

Comment: Are you on a Mac? If so, what version information do you get from gcc?

Answer (score 1):

Running gcov from the folder the code was compiled worked for me.

At the top of the .gcov file it states the complete file path. Ex.:

```
         -:    0:Source:tmp.c
         -:    0:Graph:tmp.gcno
         -:    0:Data:tmp.gcda
         -:    0:Runs:1
         -:    0:Programs:1
         -:    1:#include <stdio.h>
         -:    2:
         -:    3:int main (void)
```

If it is in a different folder, i.e, /path/tmp.c, do:

```
gcov ./path/tmp.c -o ./path/tmp
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-04/msg00080.html

Answer (score 0):

In a case when source file cannot be found there is a suggest to use absolute paths within compiling. Instead of using "../".

Secondly, you could try to copy gcno and gcda files to match "../../code/lib/src/lib1/a.c".

Or to fix building rules to make sure that no broken relative paths applied (like ../../)